# Previous month in HIVE

Tags: hive, monthcalendar

I need to pull data for the previous month in an automated script.  Below is how I do it in SQL.  I currently run the process on the 4th of the month, getting data for the previous month.  Now I need to use HIVE.  Is there a way to script this in HIVE?

**date_field >= ADD_MONTHS(DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE)+1, -1) and
date_field <= ADD_MONTHS(DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE)+1, 0)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
 date_field >= (year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))*100+month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())))-1
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Since my date_field is in the YYYY-MM-DD format, I added year(data_date)*100+month(data_date) = (year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))*100+month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())))-1 and now everything works.